# Access Beanstalk Environment Properties in docker-compose file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Beanstalk environment running on Docker Platform. I have an application bundle which contains docker-compose.yaml and .env file.
There are some sensitive information like DATABASE_USER and DATABASE_PASSWORD stored in .env file which I no longer want to store since we will be pushing this bundle to GitHub. I would like to access the environment properties from Beanstalk.
But the deployment is failing in Beanstalk when I upload the bundle with these changes.

I have defined these values DATABASE_USER and DATABASE_PASSWORD as environment properties in Beanstalk. And changed the values in the following files -

.env file

DATABASE_USER=
DATABASE_PASSWORD=

docker-compose.yaml

- DATABASE_PASSWORD=<%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
- DATABASE_USER=<%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>

I have gone through this doc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-env-cfg.env-variables
But I already have an .env in my bundle, my requirement is to not store those information in .env any longer and docker-compose should read the values from the environment properties in Beanstalk (instead of .env)
How should I access the environment properties (in Beanstalk) in docker-compose file